# Variable initialization and loops

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I'm new to coding and was trying to make a hangman game. My code works but it does not add and remove letters from the sets above. Could somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance. The code is written below;

```
from random_word import RandomWords
import string
lives = 160
number_of_plays = 0
all_letters = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
print("Please type a letter to play or 1 to quit")
print('You only have 6 chances to guess the correct word')
correct_word = RandomWords()
generated_word = correct_word.get_random_word()  # a random word

while number_of_plays < lives:
    player_command = input('> ').lower()  # player letter input
    generated_word_letters = set(generated_word)  # tabulates letters in the aforementioned word
    guessed_letters = set()  # input from the player
    correct_guessed_word = (letter if letter in guessed_letters else '_' for letter in generated_word)
    if player_command == '1':
        print('Game over')
        break
    elif player_command in all_letters:
        guessed_letters.add(player_command)
        if player_command in generated_word_letters:
            generated_word_letters.remove(player_command)
            print('Current correct guessed word: ', ''.join(correct_guessed_word))
            continue
        elif player_command not in generated_word_letters:
            number_of_plays += 1
            print('You have lost one life')
            print('You have used these letters: ', ''.join(guessed_letters))
            print('Current correct guessed word: ', ''.join(correct_guessed_word))
            continue
    elif player_command not in all_letters:
        number_of_plays += 1
        print('You have lost one life')
        print('Please type in a letter!')
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: I'm sorry i never responded to this comment but the articles you provided were helpful and made me understand debugging. I was very new to programming and thank you for taking your time to guide me to the correct path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  You just made the mistake of initializing your sets *inside* the loop.  So, what is happening is that every time your loop starts again, you are wiping out what was in them before.  Simply initialize your sets **before** jumping into the loop as shown below.  Note:  I just overrode your RandomWords with a fixed word for troubleshooting.  Nice game!

```
#from random_word import RandomWords
import string
lives = 160
number_of_plays = 0
all_letters = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
print("Please type a letter to play or 1 to quit")
print('You only have 6 chances to guess the correct word')
#correct_word = RandomWords()
generated_word = "lunch" #correct_word.get_random_word()  # a random word

generated_word_letters = set(generated_word)  # tabulates letters in the aforementioned word
guessed_letters = set()  # input from the player


while number_of_plays < lives:
    player_command = input('> ').lower()  # player letter input
    correct_guessed_word = (letter if letter in guessed_letters else '_' for letter in generated_word)
    if player_command == '1':
        print('Game over')
        break
    elif player_command in all_letters:
        guessed_letters.add(player_command)
        if player_command in generated_word_letters:
            generated_word_letters.remove(player_command)
            print('Current correct guessed word: ', ''.join(correct_guessed_word))
            continue
        elif player_command not in generated_word_letters:
            number_of_plays += 1
            print('You have lost one life')
            print('You have used these letters: ', ''.join(guessed_letters))
            print('Current correct guessed word: ', ''.join(correct_guessed_word))
            continue
    elif player_command not in all_letters:
        number_of_plays += 1
        print('You have lost one life')
        print('Please type in a letter!')
```

Comment: Hey AirSquid, I'd like to thank you for helping me with this...My journey into software development has been smooth since this and i really want to thank you!

Comment: Awesome.  Great to hear!

Comment: Last time I come to this post. I just got my first junior role recently and while at this time, this question seems embarrassing as i am far better at programming right now, i would sincerely want to thank you so much. I was very frustrated at this time and the fact that you took your time to guide me to understand a simple loop made me not give up. If you're ever in Kenya, hit me up!

Comment: All good, my friend!  We all start somewhere and if you haven't gooned up a few dozen looping operations, you haven't started yet.  lol.